# Sample Timeout not supported in all Sampler

Tags: jmeter

[Sample Timeout](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Sample_Timeout) is a useful tool for preventing "stuck" request that pauses the test, but it seems that it isn't fully supported:

> For this to work, the sampler must implement Interruptible. The following samplers are known to do so:
>
> AJP, BeanShell, FTP, HTTP, Soap, AccessLog, MailReader, JMS Subscriber, TCPSampler, TestAction, JavaSampler

For example SmtpSampler can't be interrupted with Sample Timeout.

Is there a specific reason some samplers can't be interrupted or should an enhancement be open for Smtp sampler or all samplers?

Is [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) is a better way to achieve same requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for some samplers not being interruptible is that they don't implement :

> org.apache.jmeter.samplers.Interruptible

The reason behind this, is just lack of time, so yes you can open an enhancement and contribute a PR if you like.

Runtime Controller doesn't interrupt running samplers, it will just not call some of it's children if some time has been exceeded. So I think it does not answer the requirement.